# System.IO.IOException: Error -4077 ECONNRESET connection reset by peer

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have a high traffic website behind iis load balancer and cloudflare.

i'm using    `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.1",`

and  `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",`

but i'm constantly getting this error and all request are gets dropped

what should i do?

`System.IO.IOException: Error -4077 ECONNRESET connection reset by peer ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -4077 ECONNRESET connection reset by peer --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.SocketInput.CheckConnectionError() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.SocketInputExtensions.<PeekAsyncAwaited>d__3.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.MessageBody.ForContentLength.d__4.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.MessageBody.<ReadAsyncAwaited>d__12.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.BufferedReadStream.<EnsureBufferedAsync>d__37.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream.<ReadAsync>d__36.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.IO.StreamReader.<ReadBufferAsync>d__102.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.IO.StreamReader.<ReadToEndAsyncInternal>d__67.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartSectionStreamExtensions.<ReadAsStringAsync>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.<InnerReadFormAsync>d__18.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenStore.<GetRequestTokensAsync>d__3.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at`

Comment: Hard to say with so little information. Are you using async all the way and only for true async operations? No CPU intensive stuff? No Task.Run? On the first glare it seems you are reaching thread starvation (no threads available to handle new requests), but its hard to say what cause it. You'll have to profile your application to find out where its slow and where it could be optimized

Comment: how to profile an asp.net core app?. no there are no cpu or threading issues that im aware of

Comment: Set up a test environment, run profiler, use a took like wrk to generate the requests, the analyze the profile, which requests require most time, where is the bottleneck, where high memory allocations, etc. That kind of stuff you should know and do before starting writing an app for a high-traffic site, not afterwards